# Azure AD B2C: email verification code expiration?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When signing up for a B2C account, the service sends a verification code to the email account used in the sign-up form.

I have not been able to find info on Microsoft's site specific to the following questions:

1. How long is that verification code valid?
2. Can we change that duration?
3. What assurances are in place to prevent brute force guessing of the verification code?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Custom policies can now use [Custom Email Verification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email), which also allows you to specify the expiration of the code (and all of the content). You can also control the brute force aspect you mentioned. However it requires you to send the email yourself, for example through SendGrid.

However: the current maximum expiration time that can be set seems to be 20 minutes (1200 seconds). The default value is 10 minutes(600 seconds).

There is too much code involved to copy all of the MSDN Article. These are probably the most relevant parts.

```xml
<DisplayControls>
  <DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
    <DisplayClaims>
      <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
      <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
    </DisplayClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <Actions>
      <Action Id="SendCode">
        <ValidationClaimsExchange>
          <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
          <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendGrid" />
        </ValidationClaimsExchange>
      </Action>
      <Action Id="VerifyCode">
        <ValidationClaimsExchange>
          <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
        </ValidationClaimsExchange>
      </Action>
    </Actions>
  </DisplayControl>
</DisplayControls>

...

<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>One time password technical profiles</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="GenerateOtp">
      <DisplayName>Generate one time password</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">GenerateCode</Item>
        <Item Key="CodeExpirationInSeconds">1200</Item>
        <Item Key="CodeLength">6</Item>
        <Item Key="CharacterSet">0-9</Item>
        <Item Key="ReuseSameCode">true</Item>
        <Item Key="MaxNumAttempts">5</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otp" PartnerClaimType="otpGenerated" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>

    <TechnicalProfile Id="VerifyOtp">
      <DisplayName>Verify one time password</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">VerifyCode</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessage.VerificationHasExpired">You have exceed the maximum time allowed.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessage.MaxRetryAttemped">You have exceed the number of retries allowed.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessage.InvalidCode">You have entered the wrong code.</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessage.ServerError">Cannot verify the code, please try again later.</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" PartnerClaimType="otpToVerify" />
      </InputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
   </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: This feature is still in preview and there is no way to guarantee it be usable

Comment: Thank you for this information. Since custom policies themselves were public preview for so long, I dismissed that part. Will update the answer.

Comment: Worth noting that in this case you have to rely on an external service (SendGrid in this case) to send an email.

Setting up expiration with the B2C default mailing service does not seem possible. As [the technical profile used for sending and verifying OTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/aad-sspr-technical-profile) does not have an option to set expiration time.

Comment: @milorad that is correct. We call our own REST endpoint and send the mail through MD graph. However this is still a separate service to set up and maintain. I also added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How long is that verification code valid? It is valid for 45 minutes

Can we change that duration?
**No**

What assurances are in place to prevent brute force guessing of the verification code?
**Throttling**, From the [self-service password reset docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-passwords-troubleshoot#troubleshoot-the-password-reset-portal) (which is what Azure AD B2C uses for the verification code:

[image]

Comment: Is the 45 minutes still the current timeout? I just got a timeout within 20 minutes and getting reports of closer to 5 minutes.

Comment: This is not the case for AzureAD B2C, you have added references to Azure AD

Answer (score 0):

It last 5 minutes and it can not be changed

Comment: Can you provide your source for this information, please?

Comment: I am for the first time noticing this behavior in B2C - So I think they changed a default recently  - I need to know if there is a way to make it just a bit longer   6 or 7 minutes maybe

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55686408/244191) is the best source I've been able to find. I also just confirmed this experimentally.