# B2C Password Reset verification code is expired too soon. How can I extend this time and what is default expiry time?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Currently I am using B2C standard password reset policy for changing password. During password reset journey B2C sending code to email and validate code for password reset. Currently this code is expiring almost immediately. How can I extend this expire time.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure AD B2C: email verification code expiration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010064/azure-ad-b2c-email-verification-code-expiration)

Answer (score 0):

The default expiry time for email verification code is **5 minutes** and we can not extend it. It seems like you are getting emails after that time period.

For now you can disable email verification system. Please check the below documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-disable-ev

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is the 5 minutes expiration time documented anywhere?